# How to generate a string of concatenated key/value pairs in a script?

Tags: shell, busybox, ash

I need to build a string of `--build-arg` parameter using some key/value pairs (build.args file) in a busybox shell:

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
one=$1
two=$2
shift

while IFS= read -r line; do
    set "$@" --build-arg "$line"
done < "build.args"

echo "$@"
```

**build.args**

```
ONE=first
TWO=second
```

Running `sh script.sh foo bar` (yes, two parameters are needed for the script) should read the content of build.args and add the key/value pairs as `--build-arg` parameter and output this generated string. This is what I am expecting:

```
--build-arg ONE=first --build-arg TWO=second
```

But with my script I do get

```
bar --build-arg ONE=first --build-arg TWO=second
```

as `bar` is passed as second parameter in the script call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting `bar` in there because that's what `$1` is after your `shift` operation before the loop.

To shift off two positional parameters, use `shift 2`. However, it may be safer to clear the list of positional parameters before the loop by replacing `shift` with `set --`. That way, you don't rely on the user supplying the correct number of parameters. Some shells would issue a diagnostic message if you tried to shift off more values than in the list, and if the user gives you too few or too many values, these would still be in `"$@"`.

Also, you will need to use `set --` in place of plain `set` when setting positional parameters, both in this case and in general, to avoid accidentally setting shell options or, as in this case, invoking `set` with invalid options.

```bsh
set -- "$@" --build-arg "$line"
```

Comment: It's not only *in general* that you need the `--`. It applies to this specific case. `busybox sh -c 'set --build-arg'` errors out with `sh: set: line 1: illegal option --`; `shift "$#"` is an other way  to empty `"$@"`. That and doing `set x ${1+"$@"} more; shift` was what you had to do with some shells that didn't support `set --` nor `set -` in the olden days IIRC.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sorry, I might have used the phrase "in general" to mean "always" (including any specific case).  In any case, I will update that sentence. Thanks.